# Fresh 13.04 install - Laptop Keyboard & Touchpad not working

Tags: installation, 13.04

I'm installing 13.04 (64 bit) from DVD on an Alienware M17x R4 laptop, dual-booting with Win 7.

Within the installer/live CD, both mouse and touchpad work. However, after installation when I boot into Ubuntu, neither mouse nor touchpad work - I'm stuck at the login screen. Ctrl+Alt+Fn doesn't drop me into a terminal either.

If I boot into Ubuntu recovery mode, I can get to the root shell etc and the keyboard works.

What I've tried:

- dpkg option in Ubuntu recovery mode
- chrooting into the install via the Live CD (probably could have used root shell in recovery mode) and running "apt-get update; apt-get upgrade"
- Installed nvidia graphcis drivers.
- Installed 
      linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
- Setting acpi=false, as well as i8042.reset in grub
- Redownloaded & did another fresh install

Similar to this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1172852 except that his recovery mode was broken and mine is not.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that I had leftover system directories from a previous linux install on the root partition. Deleting them and reinstalling 13.04 made everything work like a charm. Hopefully this helps someone!